# Looking for an occurrence in a random number

Tags: python, random, intervals

I wrote the following:

```
import random

count = 0
while count < 10000:
    num = random.uniform(0,999)
    print num
    if num == 777:
        print "Gotcha!"
        break
    count += 1
else:
    print "Done."
```

As you can see, if the generated number is 777 it outputs Gotcha.
The numbers I generate are like 3.837810489 and 5.92304723. What I need is it to keep a number and any part of it has a sequence of 777 like 4.397779210 but I did not find on Python documentation anything to help me on that task.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You have to convert the number to a string and then check if that string contains "777":

```
if "777" in str(num):
    print("Gotcha!")
```

Comment: Geez, that was so easy!
Thank you, Rawing

Comment: @Wesley if '7.77' should be a gotcha you may want to remove the '.' first